# Generating a list of lists in Python, but get the same ID of nested elements

Tags: python, list, items

So, I'm using this code:

```
list_of_lists = []
sample_list = ['1', '2', '3']

for x in range(3):
    list_of_lists.append(sample_list)

print(id(list_of_lists[0][1]),
      id(list_of_lists[1][1]),
      id(list_of_lists[2][1]))
```

And the items in sublists, actually, are the same objects!

```
>140324175479088 140324175479088 140324175479088
```

If I want to change list_of_lists[0][1] to '0', all sublists will be changed accordingly.

Why is it so? How to generate a list_of_lists from sample_list in a right way to make items in each sublist independent?

Comment: because you append the same object over and over. Use `.append(sample_list.copy())` instead.

Comment: Oh... Same result. Even with `.copy()` all items still have the same id

Comment: Actually, it works! Yes, IDs still same, just till I didn`t change any element. Thanks!

Comment: @JohnGalt that's likely because python interns string values up to a certain length

Comment: Yeah you may need to use deepcopy in some cases (import from copy module) but some values like small strings and ints will always have same id.

Comment: Thank you so much, guys! I’m really surprised by this fact. Is it a language feature? Don’t you know any article to read about this?